# AWS QuickSight - create a calculated field of the difference between a measure based fields

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I'm using aws quicksight and would like to create a calculated field of the difference value between my rows (and not in a pivot table) so I can visualize the difference between each measure

```
for example i have this data-set:

2019-05-09T10:52:02.000Z   0.45556
2019-05-09T14:52:03.000Z   0.46766
2019-05-09T18:52:03.000Z   0.47887
.
.
.
.

And i would like to add a calculated field that will show:

2019-05-09T10:52:02.000Z   0.45556  0
2019-05-09T14:52:03.000Z   0.46766  0.0121
2019-05-09T18:52:03.000Z   0.47887  0.01121
.
.
.
```

The main goal is to visualize (line chart) the change per reading i am getting....

Is it possible to do?

Should I create additional data-set with custom SQL query and join them?

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for the `difference` function that is available to analysis-level calculated fields:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/difference-function.html

So for the dataset:

```
mytime                     mymetric
------------------------   -------
2019-05-09T10:52:02.000Z   0.45556
2019-05-09T14:52:03.000Z   0.46766
2019-05-09T18:52:03.000Z   0.47887
```

The definition for your new calculated field would be something like this:

```
difference(
     sum( {mymetric} ), 
     [{mytime} ASC],
     1
)
```

Comment: Yes!this function is available only for pivot table which does not allow you to polt it or make a graph out of it :-(

Comment: are you sure this is only available for pivot tables?  the documentation does not state this and you create a calculated field using `difference` without associated it with any visualization?  what errors do you get when you try and put this calculated fields into a visualization?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work unless you are using a pivot table

Comment: please not that in the aws documents the function difference is under "table calculation function index"
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/difference-function.html